# Conda is taking too much disk space

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

It seems like conda update doesn't have a clean up. I have more than 4 Go of old unuse packages.
I usually do

```
conda update --all
```

once a week. Apparently, you have to do:

```
conda clean -p
```

to clean up and remove old package. 
Is there a comand to do update and cleanup in one line?

Comment: What's the big deal to do a `conda update --all & conda clean -p`? (that's the same pattern with `apt` in Linux, you first do an update then an upgrade)

Comment: The big problem is that at first I didn't do the clean. So I was having a huge disk space use by old unused packages. It took me a bit of time to figure why.

Comment: If you are using Linux/Mac you could easily set up an alias for `conda update --all & conda clean -p`. On Windows, it would be slightly more complicated, see: https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line As for the behavior of conda itself, there is nothing in the documentation indicating it can do it automatically on update

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To have a one liner on Windows run:

```
conda update --all & conda clean -p
```

On Linux (notice the double amperstand, as only one would run the statement in the reverse order):

```
conda update --all && conda clean -p
```

Furthermore if you want to have an alias on Windows, [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line) describes it well. On Linux it might vary (slightly) with the distribution, [here is for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/17538/666560)